# 'Controller 'ionNavBar', required by directive 'ionNavButtons', can't be found!' <ion-nav-view> error ionic framework

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm doing navigation for my ionic application using tabs like this:

```
<ion-tab title="feed" icon="ion-social-rss"
href="#/app/feed">
<ion-nav-view name="feed-tab"></ion-nav-view>
```

then when i'm adding name of this tab in a route

```
 .state('app.home', {
  url: '/feed',
  views: {
    'feed-tab' : {
      templateUrl: 'templates/feed.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl'
    }
  }
})
```

i'm getting this error 'Controller 'ionNavBar', required by directive 'ionNavButtons', can't be found!'

Here is my menu.html with back-button:

```html
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
  <ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar class="my-bar">
      <ion-nav-back-button id="my-back-button" class="button-clear">
        <i class="ion-chevron-left"></i>
      </ion-nav-back-button>

      <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon mybutton bot" menu-toggle="left">
        </button>
      </ion-nav-buttons>
     <!--  <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
        <a href="#" class="my-right-button"><i class="icon ion-funnel my-funnel"></i></a>
      </ion-nav-buttons> -->
    </ion-nav-bar>
  </ion-side-menu-content>

  <ion-side-menu side="left" class="sidemenu">
  
    <div>
      <div>
        <a href="#/app/options" class="button-icon icon ion-ios-gear-outline options" menu-toggle="left"></a>
      </div>
      <hr class="longhr">
    </div>
      <div class="all-projects"><h3>All Projects</h3></div>
    <div>
      <hr class="shorthr">
      <div class="project">
        <i class="ion-record icon-right icon-color-assertive my-circle-icon"></i>
        <h3>Super project</h3>
        <label>Subname</label>
        <ul type="disc">
          <li>First category</li>
          <li>Second category</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <section class="myseaction">
      <hr class="shorthr">
      <div class="project">
        <i class="ion-record icon-right icon-color-assertive my-circle-orange-icon"></i>
        <h3>One more project</h3>
        <label>Subname</label>
        <ul type="disc">
          <li>First category</li>
          <li>Second category</li>
        </ul>
        <label>Subname</label>
        <ul type="disc">
          <li>Third category</li>
          <li>Fourth category</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </section>
  </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>



<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top" id="tab">

  <ion-tab title="feed" icon="ion-social-rss"
    href="#/app/feed">
    <ion-nav-view name="feed-tab"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab title="selected" icon="ion-ios-star-outline"
    href="#/tab/list">
    <ion-nav-view name="selected-tab"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab title="actions" icon="ion-ios-list-outline"
    href="#/tab/actions">
    <ion-nav-view name="actions-tab"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>


  <ion-tab title="charts" icon="ion-arrow-graph-up-right"
    href="#/tab/charts">
    <ion-nav-view name="charts-tab"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab title="more" icon="ion-more"
    href="#/tab/more">
    <ion-nav-view name="more-tab"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

this is my feed.html header:

```
<ion-view>
<ion-nav-buttons side="right">
    <a href="#/app/feed-filter" class="my-right-button"><i class="icon ion-funnel my-funnel"></i></a>
</ion-nav-buttons>
<div class="bar bar-subheader 
    item-input-inset bar-light mysearchbar">
    <label class="item-input-wrapper">
      <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
      <input type="search" ng-model="query" placeholder="Search">
    </label>
  </div>
```

and this is my index.html:

```
 <body ng-app="starter">
<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
```

I've got test application, when i'm using this tabs and everything is okay, can't understand why i'm getting this error?

Comment: Please post your code so that we will get an idea to solve it..

Comment: Did you finally find a solution?